# Multiple simultaneous rest calls and use results in next set of rest calls

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following function which works fine.

```
export const create = () => {
    items.map(async (item) => {
      const id = // some function call
      const details = // some function call
      const offers = details?.offers;
  
      let index = 0;
      for (const offer of offers) {
        const body = getBody(offer, id, item);
        const token = await fetchToken(body);
        const result = await fetchResult({ token });
        console.log(result);
        console.log('==========', index++)
      }
    });
  };
```

When it comes to the for loop:

```
for (const offer of offers)
```

It can loop close to 100 times.

I am looking for a better way to perform the following 2 lines.

1st line:

```
const token = await fetchToken(body);
```

For above line, I want to async it and call all 100 times at the same time.

Wait for it all to complete first and store it cos I need these results for the next call.

Once done, do the same for the following, call in async, then store it.

2nd line:

```
const result = await fetchResult();
```

Is there a way to do this? `Promise.all()` seems promising, forgive the pun.

But I end up with all null when I do the following.

```
export const create = async () => {
    const tokenPromises = items.map(async (locale) => {
      const id = // some function call
      const details = // some function call
      const offers = id?.offers;
  
      const tokenPromises = offers.map((offer) => {
        const body = getBody(offer, id, item);
        return fetchToken(body);
      });
  
      return Promise.all(tokenPromises);
    });
  
    const tokensByItem = await Promise.all(tokenPromises);
  
    const resultPromises = items.map(async (locale, i) => {
      const tokens = tokensByItem[i];
  
      const resultPromises = tokens.map((token) => {
        return fetchResult({ token });
      });
  
      return Promise.all(resultPromises);
    });
  
    const dataByLocale = await Promise.all(resultPromises);
  
    dataByLocale.forEach((data, i) => {
      data.forEach((srl) => {
        console.log(srl);
        console.log('==========', i);
      });
    });
  };
```